# Ctrl+B curves rest of the edges

Tags: bevel

I am a Blender beginner and I have the following problem.
When I do ctrl + b between those two edges it curves weirdly edges I don't want to curve:
[image]

I already applied the scale to this object. How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks as if you may have overlapping or duplicate geometry. Try selecting All in Edit mode then 'M' > Merge by Distance. If that doesn't fix it please share your file so that we can have a look: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions on that page.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2vVVaw0b" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2vVVaw0b/) - I think this is it, I removed vertices but it's still stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inverted normals on your object. You can turn on the <kbd>Face Orientation</kbd> overlay as shown on the image below. Inverted face orientation is shown in <kbd>red</kbd> and <kbd>blue</kbd> is ok.

[image]

Select All in Edit mode and use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals giving the result below.

[image]

The areas still in red are the inside of the object and the seperate tabliczka object which may need changing too but you'll now be able to bevel the podstawka2 object normally as shown below.

[image]